# ¿ Por qué no puedo mostrar mi imagen almacenada en Modelo (404) Django?

Tags: python, django, imagen

Tengo un modelo donde específico que dentro de la ruta staticfiles tengo una carpeta llamada uploads donde se almacenan estas imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tiene un formulario para recibir la imagen el cual no esta siendo usado, ya que el formulario al que pertenece proviene de modelo Usuario, pero el modelo de estas fotos se llama UserProfile con fines de prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo ver en el admin de la web puedo ver la colección de las imágenes de perfil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedo seleccionar que usuario de los usuarios existentes quiero que tenga una imagen y seleccionar una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo ver en donde se almacena dentro de la carpeta core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo ver el nombre en específico del ultimo archivo que acabo de subir, en la ubicación antes especificada, lo que me dice que ese archivo sí existe para el sistema más no puedo ver la imagen aparece rota

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y No puede obtener nada de esta ruta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema consiste en no poder mostrar mi imagen pero si obtener la ruta de esta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar los archivos de la carpeta "media" para poder hacer lo que dices, los archivos estáticos en la carpeta "static" no te ayudaran para poder hacer eso, son estáticos que se llamaran una vez en tu html.

Answer (score 0):

Por completar la respuesta de Mario Luis, que creo que está en lo correcto:

Revisa la configuración de este tipo de archivos en tu `settings.py`. Podrías utilizar algo similar a esto:

```
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static_collected')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Cuando quieras mostrar tu imagen en tu `template`, puedes utilizar `object.avatar.url` para poner, por ejemplo, en el `src` del anchor, en lugar de hacerlo en el estático, como decía el compañero Mario.